# Lumen auto increment relationship create stays at 0

Tags: php, sqlite, eloquent, lumen

I have a class `Chat` :

```
class Chat extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'chat_id';
    protected $guarded    = [];

    public function comment()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Comments::class, 'comment_id', 'comment_id');
    }
}
```

And a class `Comments` :

```
class Comments extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'comment_id';
    protected $guarded    = [];
}
```

Here's the migration for the `Comments` table :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('comment_id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index('comments_user_id');
        $table->boolean('mark');
        $table->string('nick_name', 15)->nullable();
        $table->text('comment', 65535);
    });
}
```

And `Chat` has a column named `comment_id`.

When I create a `Comments` using `Eloquent` basic way, everything is fine, the `Comments.comment_id` starts at 1 and next `Comments.comment_id` columns will get incremented :

```
$comment = Comments::create([
                'user_id' => 1,
                'mark' => 50,
                'comment' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor es at'
            ]); // $comment->comment_id = 1
```

But whenever I create it through the `Chat` relationship, the `Comments.comment_id` is **always** equal to 0 :

```
$comment = $chat->comment()->create([
                'user_id'    => 1,
                'mark'       => 50,
                'comment'    => 'Lorem ipsum dolor es at',
            ]); // $comment->comment_id = 0
```

I say **always**, because creating two `Comments` in a row with the relationship will throw a UNIQUE constraint exception on the `Comments.comment_id` field.

Is there an error in my configurations ?
By the way I'm using SQLite (this happened while testing), if that's of any interest.

Answer (score 1):

The Chat relationship should be a belongsTo relationship, not hasOne.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although it doesn't seem to work either, maybe I'm using the relationship badly ?